# In what form should my features be in when running a model trained on features transformed through Weights of Evidence?

Tags: anomaly-detection, variance-inflation-factor, feature-scaling

I have trained an anomaly detection model on features transformed/selected by means of the Weights of Evidence and Variance Inflation Factor approaches.

My question is how should I go about running this model in "production"? If my set of initial features was reduced from around 200 to say 24 after WOE and VIF, when testing against live samples should I simply use the 24 features that the model was trained on (not considering further retraining in this scenario) and perform WOE on these again in order to have the features scaled in the same form as the model was trained on, or could I make use of another feature scaling approach?

For context I am using a One-class SVM in Python.